# Кроссплатформенная разработка на Scheme

Tags: android-sdk, lisp, emacs, scheme

Начал использовать [lambdanative](http://www.lambdanative.org/), основанный на [Gambit Scheme](http://gambitscheme.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), всё компилируется и работает, однако не могу понять, как в Gambit C полноценно отлаживать приложение в стиле итеративной lisp разработки, так как под него [geiser](http://www.nongnu.org/geiser/) в EMACS настроить не удалось.

Суть вопроса - как сделать, чтобы я видел запущенное приложение (так же, как оно выглядит, скомпилированным в эмуляторе Android SDK и iOS) и мог добавлять в него функциональность через REPL, в реальном времени?

Возможно, есть лучший путь - ведь тот-же geiser хорошо интегрирован с Chicken Scheme (более популярный чем Gambit) и guile (стандартный язык GNU) - может быть полезнее портировать функциональность lambdanative на один из них, чтобы получить комфортную среду... Но это и оверинжиниринг, ведь именно Gambit-C в данном случае уже хорошо работает с платформами, т.е. вопрос всё-таки в том, как выглядит правильный цикл работы с Gambit.

Comment: https://github.com/part-cw/lambdanative/issues/74

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавлю в виде ответа.
Вопрос решён, в комментарии от 3 окт '15 есть ссылка на мой тред с авторами, в документации появился раздел Debugging и пример конфигурации:
https://github.com/part-cw/lambdanative/wiki/Debugging